# Automatic download launch

Tags: javascript, download

Is there any other way to launch an automatic download. Currently we do it this way.

```
If download does not start click here: 
            <a href="http://www.example.com/file.zip">Filename (121 MB)</a>
```

And much later on in the page we have this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
          setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href='http://www.example.com/file.zip';},2000);
          };
</script>
```

Problem is that it sometime launches the same file to download multiple times to end users. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I've read that most of browsers & antivirus software block multiple downloads especially when you are using JS to run it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have an `IFrame` hidden in page with `src` pointing to zip file to download.

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="frmDld" src="http://www.example.com/file.zip"></iframe>
</div>
```

Another option will be to write the file to response stream when sending the page back(Don't know what you are using on server side. If it is asp.net/mvc then I can help.).

Answer (score 0):

If

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/file.zip">Filename (121 MB)</a>
```

works then this should work too:

```
<?php
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"0; URL= http://www.example.com/file.zip \">";
?>
```